# How to produce a "self-contained" static library?

Tags: dependencies, cmake, static-libraries

I develop a framework under the form of a shared library (in Linux). A user asked for a static version of the library. I use cmake and therefore just switched BUILD_SHARED_LIBS to OFF. I ended up with a static library as expected.

However, the user complained that he has now to link against boost and hdf5 that are dependencies of my library.

Do you think that I have to take action to avoid this situation ? Or is it normal ? Is it ever possible to provide a library that has no dependencies ?

EDIT: Should I do something like extracting the object files from the boost and hdf5 static libraries and add them when building my own ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boost' solution is:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON) # it may help
find_package(Boost REQUIRED ...)
```

For hdf5 you could try something like this.

1. Find the HDF static library with FIND_LIBRARY
2. Copy the static library into a directory in your build tree with

   `EXEC_PROGRAM( ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${HDF_LIB} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/HDFStaticLib)`
3. Add the link directory for HDFStaticLib first with

   `LINK_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/HDFStaticLib)`
4. Add the library like this:

   `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(foo ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/HDFStaticLib/HDF)`

One more thing: you should have renamed API.a to libAPI.a, if the file name does not start by lib.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the boost solution, but it didn't help. When linking a binary with my framework I still have to specify the boost library which is not the case when my framework is distributed as a shared library.
I might have misunderstood what you proposed though.

Comment: @Barth: [theoretically good. :)](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#module:FindBoost) `SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)` may help.